# xcb_poll_for_event causes 100% usage of one cpu core

Tags: c, linux, xcb

I'm learning c and messing around with xcb lib (instead of X11) on a raspberry pi4.
The problem is that when implementing the events loop with **xcb_poll_for_event** instead of **xcb_wait_for_event**, one core of four is 100% full. What am I doing wrong? And is there any benefit of using wait_for_event (blocking way) instead of xcb_poll_for_event(non blocking)?
The goal is to create a window where the user interact with keyboard/mouse/gamepad on objects, like a game. Can anyone give a hand?
The relevant code is:

```
int window_loop_test(xcb_connection_t *connection, Display *display){
  
      /* window loop non blocked waiting for events */
      int running = 1;
      while (running) {
          xcb_generic_event_t *event = xcb_poll_for_event(connection);
          if (event) {
              switch (event->response_type & ~0x80) {
              case XCB_EXPOSE: {
                  // TODO
                  break;
              }
              case XCB_KEY_PRESS: {
                  /* Quit on 'q' key press */
                  /* write key pressed on console */
  
                  const xcb_key_press_event_t *press =
                      (xcb_key_press_event_t *)event;
                  XKeyEvent keyev;
                  keyev.display = display;
                  keyev.keycode = press->detail;
                  keyev.state = press->state;
  
                  char key[32];
  
                  XLookupString(&keyev, key, sizeof(key) - 1, NULL, NULL);
  
                  // key[len] = 0;
                  printf("Key pressed: %s\n", key);
                  printf("Mod state: %d\n", keyev.state);
  
                  if (*key == 'q')
                      running = 0;
  
                  break;
              }
              }
              free(event);
          }
      }
  
      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: This is the exact difference between polling and waiting. Polling results in "busy waiting". That is, most of the time it is just checking and finding no event. But that check requires active CPU processing and thus the 100% load. Waiting on the other hand puts the process to sleep and does not consume any CPU until it is woken up by an event.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Makes sense, but it's a kind of weird because I've never seen (or maybe, I've never notice) an application/game that uses 100% of a core doing nothing. Then is there any advantage of using one instead of the other?

Comment: You haven't seen it because that is the wrong way to do it. Someone writing a real application would generally not purposely do busy waiting - that would be a bug that they would fix before releasing the application. The advantage? Didn't you already discover that yourself? One wastes the CPU resources doing no useful work and affects the whole system. The other is efficient and only consumes the minimum CPU needed to complete the job.

Comment: @kaylum, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polling and waiting each have their advantages and are good for different situations. Neither is "wrong" *per se*, but you need to use the correct one for your specific use case.

`xcb_wait_for_event(connection)` is a *blocking* call. The call will not return until an event is available, and the return value is is that event (unless an error occurs). It is good for situations where you only want the thread to respond to events, but otherwise not do anything. In that case, there is no need to spend CPU resources when no events are coming in.

`xcb_poll_for_event(connection)` is a *non-blocking* call. The call always returns immediately, but the result will be `NULL` if no event is available. It is good for situations where you want the thread to be able to do useful work even if no events are coming in. As you found out, it's not good if the thread only needs to respond to events, as it can consume CPU resources unnecessarily.

You mention that your goal is to create a game or something similar. Given that there are many ways to architect a game, either function can be suitable. But there are a couple of basic things to keep in mind that will determine which function you want to use. There may be other considerations as well, but this will give you an idea of what to look out for.

First of all, is your input system running on the same thread as other systems (simulation, rendering, etc)? If so, it's probably important to keep that thread available for work other than waiting for input events. In this case, `xcb_poll_for_event()` is almost required, otherwise your thread will be blocked until an event comes in. However, if your input system is on its own thread that doesn't block your other threads, it may be acceptable to use `xcb_wait_for_event()` and let that thread sleep when no events are coming in.

The second consideration is how quickly you need to respond to input events. There's often a delay in waking up a thread, so if fast response times are important you'll want to avoid letting the thread sleep in the first place. Again, `xcb_poll_for_event()` will be your friend in this case. If response times are not critical, `xcb_wait_for_events()` is an option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Very very useful. But here is something that I'm missing: if I have a non-blocking call and if I have no events, it breaks the loop. Then I must have this loop inside another one to have my window on the screen and I understand now that is the cause of cpu load. Then, how useful can it be xcb_poll_for_event? (because with no event the window loop breaks...)

Comment: @PedroGalriça you are right, you might need another loop. Games usually have a loop like this: `while(window_open()) { while(poll_for_events()) { /* handle events */ } draw_frame(); }`. Some games do frame-rate limiting, they (for example) _make the thread sleep for a certain amount of time_ so that not too many frames get drawn, this is also why they do not have 100% CPU usage.